# Why the calculation is not right?

Tags: c++, pointers, initialization, return-value, calculator

Here is my code :-

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int Add (int *x , int *y)
{
    int a=*x;
    int b=*y;
    int c=a+b;

    return (c);
}

int Sub (int *x , int *y)
{
    int a=*x;
    int b=*y;
    int c=a-b;

    return (c);
}

int Mul (int *x , int *y)
{
    int a=*x;
    int b=*y;
    int c=a*b;

    return (c);
}

int Div (int *x , int *y)
{
    int a=*x;
    int b=*y;
    int c=a/b;

    return (c);
}

int Mod (int *x , int *y)
{
    int a=*x;
    int b=*y;
    int c=a%b;

    return (c);
}



int InputFunction (int *a , int *b , char op)
{
    int x=*a;
    int y=*b;
    int c=0;

    cout<<"Please enter first number : ";
    cin>>x;

    cout<<"Please enter second number : ";
    cin>>y;

    cout<<endl;

    cout<<"Please choose an operator to perform the operation :- "<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<" \t \t \t + for addition"<<endl;
    cout<<" \t \t \t - for sunbtraction"<<endl;
    cout<<" \t \t \t x for mutiplication"<<endl;
    cout<<" \t \t \t / for division"<<endl;
    cout<<" \t \t \t % for modulus"<<endl<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<" \t \t    Your choice : ";
    cin>>op;

    switch (op)
    {
        case '+':
                 Add (&x , &y);
                 break;

        case '-':
                 Sub (&x , &y);
                 break;

        case 'x':
                 Mul (&x , &y);
                 break;

        case '/':
                 Div (&x , &y);
                 break;

        case '%':
                 Mod (&x , &y);
                 break;

        default:
                 cout<<"Your symbol is not recognized!";
                 break;
    }

    int i=c;


    return (i);
}

int main()
{
    int a=0;
    int b=0;
    char op;
    char ch;
    int i;

    do
    {
    InputFunction (&a , &b , op);

    int m=i;

    cout<<" \t \t Your answer : "<<m<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"Do you want to repeat the program ? (Y/N) ";
    cin>>ch;

    }while (ch == 'Y' || ch == 'y');

    cout<<"Good- Bye"<<endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Why some weird long answer is calculated? Also the compiler shows warnings that `op` and `i` in `main()` function are not initialized (although they are initialized above). I'm new to C++. Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please narrow down the code to the part that is problematic? And what "weird long answer"? Can you please show actual (and expected) output for some input?

Comment: You are not changing the local variable i.

Comment: it should be: `int m = InputFunction (&a , &b , op);` and I don't see the point of passing parameters to input function...

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Example :- 8 + 8 should be 16 but it's showing -858993460

Comment: @SHR So instead of `int m=i;`, I should write `int m=InputFunction (&a , @&b , op);`? And yes, no point in passing parameters but I'm doing this for a reason.

Comment: In C++ as in the real world, the fact that two things have the same name doesn't make them the same thing.

Comment: Did you enable compiler warnings? That should tell you exactly what's wrong.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Yes the compiler **was** already giving me warnings. Please see the entire page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modified the code for you. The actual problem is you are not assigning the return values. i in your InpuFunction and i in your main methods are different. Unless you return the value from InputFunction (called method) to main function (the caller method), your value won't change.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int Add (int *x , int *y)
{

  int a=*x;
  int b=*y;
  int c=a+b;

  return (c);
}

int Sub (int *x , int *y)
{
  int a=*x;
  int b=*y;
  int c=a-b;

  return (c);
}

int Mul (int *x , int *y)
{
  int a=*x;
  int b=*y;
  int c=a*b;

  return (c);
}

int Div (int *x , int *y)
{
  int a=*x;
  int b=*y;
  int c=a/b;

  return (c);
}

int Mod (int *x , int *y)
{
  int a=*x;
  int b=*y;
  int c=a%b;

  return (c);
}



int InputFunction (char op)
{
  int x;
  int y;
  int c=0;

  cout<<"Please enter first number : ";
  cin>>x;
  cout<<"Please enter second number : ";
  cin>>y;
  cout << " x = " << x << " y = " << y << endl; 

  cout<<endl;

  cout<<"Please choose an operator to perform the operation :- "<<endl<<endl;
  cout<<" \t \t \t + for addition"<<endl;
  cout<<" \t \t \t - for sunbtraction"<<endl;
  cout<<" \t \t \t x for mutiplication"<<endl;
  cout<<" \t \t \t / for division"<<endl;
  cout<<" \t \t \t % for modulus"<<endl<<endl<<endl;
  cout<<" \t \t    Your choice : ";
  cin>>op;


  switch (op)
    {
    case '+':
      c = Add (&x , &y);
      break;

    case '-':
      c = Sub (&x , &y);
      break;

    case 'x':
      c = Mul (&x , &y);
      break;

    case '/':
      c = Div (&x , &y);
      break;

    case '%':
      c = Mod (&x , &y);
      break;

    default:
      cout<<"Your symbol is not recognized!";
      break;
    }
  cout << "c is " << c << endl;
  int i=c;


  return (i);
}

int main()
{

  char op;
  char ch;
  int i;

    do
      {
    int m = InputFunction (op);

    cout<<" \t \t Your answer : "<<m<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"Do you want to repeat the program ? (Y/N) ";
    cin>>ch;

      }while (ch == 'Y' || ch == 'y');

    cout<<"Good- Bye"<<endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Thanks man. But what about the warnings that the compiler shows?

Comment: Which compiler are you using ? I am using GNU C++ compiler and I am not seeing any warnings.

Comment: Microsoft visual studio compiler. It says 
`'i' : unreferenced local variable`   and  
`local variable 'op' used without having been initialized`

Comment: The variable i in main method is unused and try assign a value to op , like op = -1. Some compiler may warnings if local variables are used without initializing it. In your case, main method uses op without initializing it.

Answer (score 2):

```
int InputFunction (int *a , int *b , char op)
```

You never assign the return value of your functions to anything in your main loop.

ie.,

```
int i = InputFuction(...);
int a = Add(1, 2);
int b = Sub(1, 2);
// etc.
```

You have the same issue with all of your functions (Add, Sub, Mul, etc.). The return value isn't getting assigned to anything.

Comment: He seems to be making the assumption that if you have two variables in different functions with the same name, that they'll magically be linked and have the same value.

Comment: @benjymous I agree, especially when I saw how the OP defined the return value (i). But I believe the above will fix the problem regardless.

Comment: That won't fix it alone, as he makes the same mistake calling Add, Sub, etc, inside InputFunction

Answer (score 1):

As for the compiler warnings, you have declared `op` and `i`, but not initialized them with a value (as you did with `a` & `b`).

As for the output, what output are you actually getting?

Comment: 8 + 8 should be 16 but its giving me -858993460. Should I initialize i with 0? What would you say about the same for op?

Comment: As `i` is used as the answer of the operation, assign `i` with the output from `InputFunction`, as the other answers already noted. For `op`, you should ask your user what he wants to calculate (in the same fashion as you already do with `ch` being either "Y" or "y").

Answer (score 1):

For the warnings, when you declare a local variable, its value is not set. That means its value is indeterminate and using it will lead to undefined behavior.

You need to initialize local variables before you use them. Incidentally it may be the root cause of your problem.

You might want to do e.g.

```
i = InputFunction (&a, &b, op);
```

Or even better, you don't really need the `i` variable (or `op`) in the `main` function, so

```
m = InputFunction (&a, &b);
```

should be enough (after you change the `InputFunction` to not take the `op` as argument).